# Is showing x-amz-credential or any amazon stuff publicly okay in form?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my form it showing my policy and x-amz-credential, x-amz-alorithm, x-amz-signature, my bucket, etc...

```
data-form-data = "{"key":"/uploads/temporary/<some random numbers/letters>/${filename}",
                   "success_action_status":"201",
                   "acl":"public-read",
                   "Content-Type":"image/jpeg",
                   "policy":"<bunch of random numbers/letters",
                   "x-amz-credential":"<your-access-key-id>/<date>/<aws-region>/<aws-service>/aws4_request",
                   "x-amz-algorithm":"<some random numbers/lettering>",
                   "x-amz-date":"<some random numbers/letters>",
                   "x-amz-signature":"<some random numbers/letters>"}"
data-url="https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com"
data-hose="<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.  It's designed not to expose sensitive data, and this data isn't sensitive.

Your AWS Access Key **Secret** is the only value that is secret and must not be revealed.  (There's also a sensitive intermediate value called the **signing key** that's generated from the secret, which you won't see unless you wrote your own V4 request signing code).   The signature is derived from the signing key and other request parameters; the signing key is service and region specific and is derived from the secret and used in your code, then discarded... and both of these values are generated using in a one-way process that makes it computationally infeasible to reverse-engineer.